# Create a file with specified memory size in Python

Tags: python-3.x, file, creation

Creation of a file with dummy data for a given memory size. Example creating file of 10 MB size.

Answer (score 2):

```
import os
cmd = ("dd if=/dev/zero of=filename.txt bs=1 count=0 seek=2G")
os.system(cmd)
```

read this post: [How to create a file with a specified memory size in Python](https://devnote.in/how-to-create-a-file-with-a-specified-memory-size-in-python)

Answer (score 1):

Fastest is not depending on Python. On Linux/OSX:

```
os.system('dd if=/dev/zero of=file.txt count=10240 bs=1024')
```

Replace `/dev/zero` with `/dev/random` if you don't like zeroes.

If you want a cross-platform solution that is not as fast, then you have to do it manually: open a file for binary writing, make a loop and write, write, write.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

MB = 1024 * 1024

def createFile(name, size):

    data = "d" * (int(size / 2) - 1)

    arr = bytearray(data, 'utf-16')
    with open(name, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(arr)
    file_size = os.stat(name).st_size
    print("File created of ", file_size / size, " MB size")

    # `enter code here`Creating 1MB of file with dummy data

createFile("test", MB)
```